# PyCharm py3 syntax issues when using py2 interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

I'd like to work on a project that's intended to support both Python 2 and Python 3.  I'm currently using a Python 2 interpreter as the default interpreter, but I'd like to get syntax highlighting on issues that would break the code for running in Python 3.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find the answer right after asking the question...  ^_^

In File > Settings > Editor > Inspections under "Python" there's a "Code compatibility inspection" that appears to do what I want.  You can check off which versions of Python you want to support.